# Smoothing line plot imperfections in R

Tags: r, plot

Consider the following plot:

```
 q1 <- c(1000000.0,  908364.8,  876009.1,  847892.8,  824808.3,  805416.2,  785266.2, 770997.1,  753908.6,  744599.9,  706777.6,  674659.9,  634654.4,  601440.4, 568259.7,  535361.3,  493679.9,  465526.5,  429766.6,  395244.7,  361483.2, 332136.6, 308574.5, 285500.6, 262166.2 ,237989.0 , 210766.1,  188578.1, 166762.3 , 140399.8  ,114865.5)
 plot(q1, type = "l", lty = 1, lwd = 2, col = "darkolivegreen3", ylim = c(0,4*10^6))
```

[image]

As you can somewhat see on the graph, the line is not drawn perfectly, but has some "chainsaw" imperfections.. Is there a parameter or a line type that could fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the issue that straight lines appear jagged due to bad [anti-aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing)? Are you plotting to a window (as opposed to a file) on a windows system?

Comment: Exactly the problem... Yes I am! Any way I can resolve this? Would plotting to a file result in higher resolution?

Comment: If you plot to a PDF file (which you should do for your presentations and publications) this shouldn’t be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anti-aliasing and other issues related to image rendering is controlled by the device you carry out the plotting on. On a windows system please refer to the [`?windows`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/grDevices/windows) help page for options and information. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any settings for anti-aliasing so then I guess it comes down to you graphics drivers. In other words, there is no quick fix.

However, you can try plotting to a file with `png` or `jpeg` instead. Even better is to plot to a vectorized file, such as `pdf` or `svg` where the concept of aliasing doesn't even apply (it is left to the device you view the file in, *e.g.* acrobat reader).